# How can I call an URL when I use setContentView()?

Tags: android

I developed a simple game and I want to give an external URL to my web page. The problem is that, I'm using setContentView in the onCreate method of my main activity. My game content is dynamic and I cannot use intents instead of setContentView. However, as you know, onCreate is called once and the only way that I found on web to call an URL is "using intents". It is not working because setContentView is the only thing running. Here is my codes:

GameActivity.java

```
private static GameContent gameContent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    gameContent = new GameContent(this);
    setContentView(gameContent);

} // on.c.ends
```

My GameContent class is extends SurfaceView and Runnable. I call all draw(), pause() and resume() methods here. I have a class BasicButton and I added it to GameContent and draw it. It works. Here is the part that I want to use:

BasicButton.java

```
@Override
public void update() {

    if (xx > (rate.getX()) && xx < (rate.getX() + rate.getPlayButton('x')))
        if (yy > (rate.getY()) && yy < (rate.getY() + rate.getPlayButton('y'))) {
            UserInput.setXY(0, 0);
            if (UserInput.getAction() == true) {
                // I want to add a code here to open a web page
            } // fi
        } // fi

} // update ends
```

My solution was to create a boolean in GameActivity and change it from BasicButton class and using an intent and startActivity, to open a web page. However it is not working.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: "// I want to add a code here to open a web page" -- assuming that `BasicButton` inherits from `View`: `getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("...")))`, where `...` is your URL. "My solution was to create a boolean in GameActivity and change it from BasicButton class and using an intent and startActivity, to open a web page. However it is not working." -- note that nobody can help you with your solution, since you did not post your solution.

Comment: My major problem is when onCreate runs, it doesn't response any of the methods in same GameMain class. If I can run this methods, problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  setContentView only works with pre-compiled XML files in your APK.  You can't even write a new one on the fly and call setContentView on it.  I don't think you really understand what setContentView does.

Comment: "setContentView only works with pre-compiled XML files in your APK" -- that's not true. You can pass in a `View`, such as `GameContent` (which apparently extends `SurfaceView`).

Comment: Ok, correct.  You can pass in a View.  But you can't pass in a URL.  My guess is he wanted to pass in an xml file via URL.

Comment: then all you say that I will never ever open a web page again?

Comment: You would do it via Intent to launch a browser.  Or you would do it via a WebView.  You would not do it by calling setContentView.